# Check IF single OR multiple custom data has been entered

Tags: custom-post-types, php, conditional-content

I'm building a single template right now for a custom post type. I'm wondering if there is a way to check if either at least one or multiple of the custom values has been entered so I can display the div accordingly. Basically, I want to display the div it has anything filled out, if it is left blank then don't show it. Is this possible?

Here is a sample snippet I have:

```
<?php IF STAEMENT HERE ?>
   <div id="downloads">
        <ul>
        <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sermon_video', true)) { ?>
            <li><a href=" <?php echo $post_meta_data['sermon_video'][0]; ?>">Video</a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sermon_audio', true)) { ?>
            <li><a href=" <?php echo $post_meta_data['sermon_audio'][0]; ?>">Audio</a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sermon_document', true)) { ?>
            <li><a href=" <?php echo $post_meta_data['sermon_document'][0]; ?>">PDF</a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>
   </div>
<?php ENDIF ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already using `get_post_custom` a slightly cleaner yet still dirty (php) way of doing it.

```
$sermondata = get_post_custom($post->ID);

if( isset($sermondata['sermon_audio']) || isset($sermondata['sermon_video']) || isset($sermondata['sermon_document']))
{ ?>
<div id="downloads">
// rest of your echo output
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

ps . Just make sure the value is not `null`, to be safe you can combine the check with `array_key_exists()` (makes it slower though).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work perfect for what I was trying to do. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Get your values first.

```
<?php 
$sermondata['sermon_video'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sermon_video', true);
$sermondata['sermon_audio'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sermon_audio', true);
$sermondata['sermon_document'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sermon_document', true);

if (!empty($sermondata)) { ?>
   <div id="downloads">
      <ul>
      <?php if(isset($sermondata['sermon_video'])) { ?>
        <li><a href=" <?php echo $post_meta_data['sermon_video'][0]; ?>">Video</a></li>
      <?php }
      if(isset($sermondata['sermon_audio'])) { ?>
        <li><a href=" <?php echo $post_meta_data['sermon_audio'][0]; ?>">Audio</a></li>
      <?php } 
      if(isset($sermondata['sermon_document'])) { ?>
        <li><a href=" <?php echo $post_meta_data['sermon_document'][0]; ?>">PDF</a></li>
      <?php } ?>
      </ul>
   </div><php 
} ?>
```

If I knew more about what  what `$sermondata` looks like it might be possible to simplify that code more.

Comment: I use this to grab all of the custom data: $post_meta_data = get_post_custom('post_type=sermons'); Is there anything else you would need to know? Thanks for the reply I will try it out.

Comment: For this example I gave, they are all text fields that are being filled out and displayed on the front end.

Comment: [`get_post_custom`s](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) only parameter should be a post ID, not a query-string-like string.  What does `var_dump(get_post_custom($post->ID))` look like?

Comment: Never noticed that, thanks for the info. It does the same thing, I switched it over to the proper way. Any idea now how I can clean the above code up?

Comment: It does the same thing because it basically defaults to 'this post'. It wouldn't work correctly outside of a Loop. I wouldn't worry about it being 'bad' code. It isn't. You might be able to do it fewer lines depending on what your meta data looks like.